# Crash on iOS 7: [NSConcreteMapTable assign:key:value:isNew:]

Tags: ios, ios7, crash, nslayoutconstraint, crashlytics

I get the next line on the crash log:
[NSConcreteMapTable assign:key:value:isNew:]
This crash happens on iOS 7, but not on iOS 8.

Somewhere before this line there are calls for NSLayoutConstraint:
-[NSLayoutConstraint _addLoweredExpression:toEngine:integralizationAdjustment:lastLoweredConstantWasRounded:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:]
-[NSLayoutConstraint _addToEngine:integralizationAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:]
-[NSLayoutConstraint _addToEngine:]

Do you guys think this crash has something to do with the Storyboard layout constraint I have set?

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x3b46d626 objc_msgSend + 5
1  Foundation                     0x315da681 -[NSConcreteMapTable assign:key:value:isNew:] + 68
2  Foundation                     0x315da5fb -[NSConcreteMapTable setObject:forKey:] + 82
3  Foundation                     0x3161daf7 -[NSISEngine setRowWithHead:body:] + 30
4  Foundation                     0x316205d1 -[NSISEngine pivotToMakeBodyVar:newHeadOfRowWithHead:andDropRow:] + 388
5  Foundation                     0x3161e325 -[NSISEngine minimizeConstantInObjectiveRowWithHead:] + 236
6  Foundation                     0x31620d9f -[NSISEngine tryUsingArtificialVariableToAddConstraintWithMarker:rowBody:usingInfeasibilityHandlingBehavior:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 226
7  Foundation                     0x3161c5fd -[NSISEngine tryToAddConstraintWithMarker:expression:integralizationAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 692
8  Foundation                     0x3161c23b -[NSLayoutConstraint _addLoweredExpression:toEngine:integralizationAdjustment:lastLoweredConstantWasRounded:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 286
9  Foundation                     0x31619f6d -[NSLayoutConstraint _addToEngine:integralizationAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 232
10 Foundation                     0x316257ed -[NSLayoutConstraint _addToEngine:] + 28
11 UIKit                          0x335c2c55 __57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke_2 + 332
12 Foundation                     0x31619b2b -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 210
13 UIKit                          0x335c2ad9 __57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke + 336
14 UIKit                          0x334cf20d -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:] + 200
15 UIKit                          0x335c2bbb __57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke_2 + 178
16 Foundation                     0x31619b2b -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 210
17 UIKit                          0x335c2ad9 __57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke + 336
18 UIKit                          0x334cf20d -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:] + 200
19 UIKit                          0x335c2bbb __57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke_2 + 178
20 Foundation                     0x31619b2b -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 210
21 UIKit                          0x335c2ad9 __57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke + 336
22 UIKit                          0x334cf20d -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:] + 200
23 UIKit                          0x335c2bbb __57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke_2 + 178
24 Foundation                     0x31619b2b -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 210
25 UIKit                          0x335c2ad9 __57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke + 336
26 UIKit                          0x334cf20d -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:] + 200
27 UIKit                          0x334cee33 __45-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]_block_invoke + 82
28 Foundation                     0x31619b2b -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 210
29 UIKit                          0x334cecd3 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 298
30 UIKit                          0x334dba4f -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 1414
31 UIKit                          0x334db4bf -[UIView(Hierarchy) addSubview:] + 30
32 UIKit                          0x335bcdb7 -[UITransitionView transition:fromView:toView:removeFromView:] + 978
33 UIKit                          0x335fcf3f -[UITransitionView transition:fromView:toView:] + 30
34 UIKit                          0x335fcf15 -[UITransitionView transition:toView:] + 104
35 UIKit                          0x335fc03b -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:transition:shouldSetSelected:] + 1106
36 UIKit                          0x335fbbdf -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:] + 38
37 UIKit                          0x335fbab7 -[UITabBarController _setSelectedViewController:] + 258
38 UIKit                          0x336c5dd5 -[UITabBarController _tabBarItemClicked:] + 272
39 UIKit                          0x33505037 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 90
40 UIKit                          0x33504fd7 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 30
41 UIKit                          0x336c5c8b -[UITabBar _sendAction:withEvent:] + 370
42 UIKit                          0x33505037 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 90
43 UIKit                          0x33504fd7 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 30
44 UIKit                          0x33504fb1 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 44
45 UIKit                          0x334f0717 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 374
46 Foundation                     0x31693163 __NSFireDelayedPerform + 414
47 CoreFoundation                 0x30c7e167 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 14
48 CoreFoundation                 0x30c7dd7f __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 782
49 CoreFoundation                 0x30c7c11b __CFRunLoopRun + 1210
50 CoreFoundation                 0x30be6ebf CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 522
51 CoreFoundation                 0x30be6ca3 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
52 GraphicsServices               0x35aec663 GSEventRunModal + 138
53 UIKit                          0x3353314d UIApplicationMain + 1136
```

Comment: Add the crash log here as well.

Comment: Added the crash log
Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems like your using iOS 8 only constraints go to the storyboard open it on the top left corner you will see a little yellow icon with reading mark on it press on it and search for iOS8 only warnings, if you find any remove those constraints and rebuild your application.

Comment: You're right. There was "Automatic Preferred Max Layout Width" warning.